# The $n$-adic integers are isomorphic to the product of the $p_i$-adic integers where the $p_i$ are the distinct prime factors of $n$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

This is a followup question to [Can you define a greatest common divisor in a commutative ring that is not a domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018211/can-you-define-a-greatest-common-divisor-in-a-commutative-ring-that-is-not-a-dom?noredirect=1#comment4142933_2018211). How do you prove rigorously that $$\mathbb{Z}_n\simeq\mathbb{Z}_{p_1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_{p_l}$$ where $p_1,\ldots,p_l$ are the distinct prime factors of $n$? What are the isomophisms if you define $$\mathbb{Z}_n=\left\{\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kn^k\mid\forall k\in\mathbb{N}_0:a_k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}\right\}$$ or $$\mathbb{Z}_n=\left\{(a_k+n^k\mathbb{Z})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\in\prod_{k=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}/n^k\mathbb{Z}\mid\forall k\in\mathbb{N}:a_k\equiv a_{k+1}\mod n^k\right\}$$ respectively?

Comment: Do you see the connection to the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do p-adic fields degenerate for non-prime $p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249312/how-do-p-adic-fields-degenerate-for-non-prime-p)