# Can we have $n$-adic integers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

I am starting to read about $p$-adic integers and one thing struck me. I have some related questions below. Can anybody help me out?

Can we have $n$-adic integers if we try to construct it in the same way? Like if we take $n=4$, then the number $10=2+4.2$, in $4$-adic integer becomes $22$?

If $n=pq$, does numbers represented in this $n$-adic form split into a number in $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_q$, where $\mathbb Z_p,\mathbb Z_q$ are fields of $p$ and $q$-adic integers? The reason I am asking it is, clearly we can represent numbers in this form which I call $n$-adic integers, in which the number $a_0a_1...a_k$, $a_i\in \mathbb{Z}_n$, can be splitted into a tuple in $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_q$, by mapping each $a_i$ to $a_i\;mod\;(p)$ and $a_i\;mod\;(q)$. Am I correct?

Comment: related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019647/the-n-adic-integers-are-isomorphic-to-the-product-of-the-p-i-adic-integers-w

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_p = \varprojlim \Bbb{Z/p^j Z}$ is the ring of limits of sequences of integers that converge $\bmod p^j$ for all $j$. It is the completion (limits of Cauchy sequences) of $\Bbb{Z}$ for the $|p^j a|_p = p^{-j}$ absolute value ($p\nmid a$).

It is not a field, $p$ has not inverse, the field is $\Bbb{Q}_p = \Bbb{Z}_p[p^{-1}]$.

Then $\Bbb{Z}_n= \varprojlim \Bbb{Z/n^j Z}$ is the ring of limits of sequences of integers that converge $\bmod n^j$ for all $j$.  It is the completion for the norm $ \|a\|_n=\sum_{p|n}|a|_p$. Yes
$\Bbb{Z}_n\cong \prod_{p|n} \Bbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Thanks.. So it has applications then? And we can define all properties of $n$-adic similar to $p$-adic? And any computation in $Z_n$ can be splitted in the decomposed rings?

Comment: Also in the same way can we define $\mathbb{Q}_n=Z_n[n^{-1}]$? And $\mathbb{Q}_n≅∏p|n\mathbb{Q}_p$? I am not sure about these... @reuns

Comment: Sure. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ok thats nice.. thanks...

Comment: Note: if $n$ is a prime power, $n=p^k$, then the ring of $n$-adic integers is isomorphic to the ring of $p$-adic integers.  If $n \ge 6$ is not a prime power, then the ring of $n$-adic integers has zero divisors.  Math students should prove these once in their life.

Comment: So, $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}[p^{-k}]$ is a field? and it's exactly $\mathbb{Q}_p$?@GEdgar

Comment: Your $10=22$ thing doesn't make sense. Is it clear to you that my first comment defines the $p$-adic integers in two ways ? One of those ways works for any $n$ and it is obvious that it gives the same for $p$ and $p^k$.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake. It males sense from your explanation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do p-adic fields degenerate for non-prime $p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249312/how-do-p-adic-fields-degenerate-for-non-prime-p)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes. Thanks!

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1919274/96384